# How to get different counts from different tables in a single select

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck trying to get different counts from different tables. This is my sql query:

```
SELECT u.foto,u.nombre, u.email, u.privado, u.id, 
count(distinct ses.idSeguido) seguidos, 
count(distinct sos.idSeguidor) seguidores,
count(t.idUsuario) as publicaciones
FROM  usuario u
LEFT JOIN seguidos AS ses ON u.id = ses.idSeguidor
LEFT JOIN seguidos AS sos ON u.id = sos.idSeguido
LEFT JOIN tablero  AS t ON u.id = t.idUsuario
where u.id = 1 and ses.aceptado and sos.aceptado
```

The result I get when the query is executed:

[image]

publicaciones must be 18, but I get 612. Seems that the others counts are affecting my last one because 612 comes from (seguidos* seguidores* publicaciones) = (2 * 17 * 18)

I try some group by, but it doesn't take the effect I expect.
Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: first start with out the count and see which result you get, then correct the query till you get the wanted result

Comment: @nbk thanks. If I remove the count I get 1 as is expected because is the ID of the where clause. I know that it have to be 18 because I use this query before: select  count(t.idUsuario) as publicaciones FROM  usuario u inner JOIN tablero  AS t ON u.id = t.idUsuario
where u.id = 1, and it works, but now I want to get more information from other tables.

Comment: if yout get the correct result the count is also correct . but even then make a [mre] so that we can see what happens

Comment: @nbk thanks. Making a simple query, I realized that I made wrong the count. The correct lines is : count(distinct t.id) as publicaciones. Thanks!